What is the origin and history of Nusach Roma?
This year I visited Italy.  There I found that, at least in Rome, the Jewish community uses a unique prayer order that differs greatly from other nuschaot, like Sephardic and Ashkenazic.  Does Rome’s nusach predate others still in use?  What are the major differences that make it unique?  Also, why did the Italians continue to keep their own nusach?

Why shouldn't they keep their nusach?

Paging @Kazibácsi

https://www.j-italy.org/libraries/the-italian-rite/

See מבוא למחזור בני רומא for detailed differences (Shadal's introduction for piyyutim, Goldschmidt for the main prayer text)

@YDJ The article you cited as a comment, answers all of my questions.  But include ba ‘s references regarding detailed differences.

@BruceJames done thank you.

The description of nussach Roma or Italian Rite is presented in the article by Etan Fiorino based on the introduction to the Siddur Benè Roma by Rav Riccardo Di Segni. Some shortened adaptation of the article to answer the OP question is as follows:
Italian Jewish community account a continuous settlement on the Apennine (Italian) peninsula for over twenty-two centuries. Traditional Hebrew name fo Italy - אי טל-י-ה - I-tal-yah - "Island of Divine Dew". Italian Jewish community follows traditions that are different from either Sephardi or Ashkenazi rites, which sets it apart from other communities in the Diaspora.

At present, it is kept alive only by a small population spread between Italy, Israel, and the Americas. It is currently maintained in Rome, Turin, and Milan, while in Florence and Venice it has merged with Sephardic and Ashkenazic traditions which imposed a different flavor... Until the Shoah, there were Italian synagogues in Mediterranean communities such as Salonica, but the devastation of those communities by the Nazis obliterated the last vestiges of Italian congregations that dated back hundreds of years. Today, outside of Italy, the Italian rite is only practiced in the Conegliano Synagogue in Jerusalem. The presence of Italian rabbis in cities including New York, Boston and Tokyo contributes to foster interest in this heritage.


... Italian Jews have kept a unique set and order of prayers, cantillation style and original liturgical songs... They also developed their own specific legal codes, Judeo-Italian dialects and folkloric traditions that are not found elsewhere. ... This multilayered set of traditions, melodies, liturgical repertoire and cantillation style is known by different names: minhag Qahal Qadosh Roma (“of the sacred community of Rome”); minhag lo’ez or lo’azim (literally: “those who speak a foreign language”, probably in Latin); or minhag Benè Roma (“of the sons of Rome”), indicating the original centrality of Rome.

Elements of the Italian nusach, one can find in the work of Sa'adia Gaon, who was born in Eretz Israel, lived in Egypt and Babylonia. It is believed that Italian nussach is one of the vestiges of the nussach of Eretz Israel, while the Babylonian rites, represented by Seder Rav Amram Gaon, became more authoritative in the Sephardi and Ashkenazi world. The rites became nore normalized around 700 CE, "due to a strong trend towards normalization of the liturgy and establishment of accepted practices emerged, leading to the development of a more fixed structure and set of prayers."

By the Middle Ages, the prayer service had become relatively fixed. ... With the development of the printing press and further standardization of the liturgy, among the first printed Hebrew texts was the Soncino prayerbook of the Italian rite, published in 1486.

Italy occupies central geographic location and, for the most part, historically it provided relatively hospitable environment for Jewish life. Many waves of immigrants from both Ashkenazi and Sephardi world, came to Italy, where they opened own synagogues next to the local Italian ones.

Although Italian Jews have clung to their distinctive liturgy even when outnumbered by Ashkenazim or Sephardim, in this environment, cross-fertilization in liturgical practices was inevitable. Thus, in spite of the perceivable distinction of the Italian rite today, when taking a closer look at it, we discover that through centuries of migrations and encounters, the original Italian canon has absorbed a significant amount of traits from other Jewish worlds. Neverteless, the Italian nusach retains much of its distinctive character that remains cherished by Italian Jews wherever they may live.

References

Rav Samuel David Luzzatto (Shadal), Introduction (Mavò) to the Machazor benè Roma, Livorno 1856, 2
Daniel Goldschmidt, “Minhag benè Roma”, Tel Aviv 1965
I.Y.Kohn, “Bibliografia shel machazorim wesiddurè tefilla italiani”, in Mavò 1965

Italian Machazorim

Italian Machazor, Soncino e Casalmaggiore, 1485-86
Machazor di rito italiano secondo gli usi di tutte le Comunità, curated by Rav Menachem Emanuele Artom, Roma 1998-Jerusalem 2005
Italian Siddùr curated by Rav Panzieri, 1935
Siddur di rito italiano secondo l’uso delle Comunità di Roma e di Milano, curated by Rav Riccardo Di Segno and Rav Elia Richetti, Morashà Milano, 2002


Please don't just copy paste a whole article here. Link to it and summarize or quote particular sections. See for instance https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/548/759
